# Missing some files in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

Can anyone tell me where to find the following files in Cygwin `setup.exe`?

```
sys/socket.h
netinet/in_systm.h
netinet/in.h
netinet/ip.h
arpa/inet.h
netdb.h
```

here is what -v is printing out

```
$ make
gcc -g -c -v it.c
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc44-svn/configure --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --host=i686-w6
4-mingw32 --disable-multilib --disable-nls --disable-win32-registry --prefix=/mi
ngw32 --with-gmp=/mingw32 --with-mpfr=/mingw32 --enable-languages=c,c++
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.4.3 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-g' '-c' '-v' '-mtune=generic'
 c:/strawberry/c/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/cc1.exe -quiet -v -ip
refix c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/ it.c -quiet -dumpba
se it.c -mtune=generic -auxbase it -g -version -o C:\Users\AppData\Local\
Temp\ccuWjX0W.s
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/strawberry/c/lib/gcc/../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/strawberry/c/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/i686-w64-min
gw32/4.4.3/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/strawberry/c/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/i686-w64-min
gw32/4.4.3/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/strawberry/c/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/i686-w64-min
gw32/4.4.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../include
 c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/include
 c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/include-fixed
 c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../i686-w64-ming
w32/include
 /mingw/include
End of search list.
GNU C (GCC) version 4.4.3 (i686-w64-mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.4.3, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 2.4.2-p
3.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 4728d1fc720cf46696475c98813fbdef
```

i think it is looking in strawberry for the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: `netinet/in_system.h` is actually spelled `netinet/in_systm.h`; I've edited your question to correct it.

These should all be part of the `cygwin` package. You can't have a working Cygwin installation without that package.

They're all under `/usr/include`.

```
$ cygcheck -c cygwin
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
cygwin               1.7.16-1       OK
$ cygcheck -l cygwin | wc -l
280
$ cygcheck -l cygwin | egrep 'sys/socket.h|netinet/in_systm.h|netinet/in.h|netinet/ip.h|arpa/inet.h|netdb.h'
/usr/include/netdb.h
/usr/include/netinet/in.h
/usr/include/netinet/in_systm.h
/usr/include/netinet/ip.h
/usr/include/arpa/inet.h
/usr/include/sys/socket.h
$
```

If those files are missing, you might try reinstalling the `cygwin` package -- but first make sure you're looking for them in the right place, under `/usr/include`.

Comment: my cygwin include file looks like this netinet/in.h, it is indeed in the directory you stated, how do i edit the file to point to the right  directory, tried using path windows C:\path to file, and that failed to see it

Comment: @spaceranger: What "cygwin include file" are you talking about? If you want to include `netinet/in.h` in a C source file, use `#include <netinet/in.h>`; the compiler knows to look in `/usr/include`.

Comment: the files are in in the /usr/include but its still giving me the missing file error

Comment: @spaceranger: *What* is giving you a "missing file error"? Please update your question to exactly show what you're doing that's giving you an error, and the exact text of the error message.

Comment: i think cygwin is looking in these strawberry for the  include files,

Comment: Please show the contents of `it.c` if it's not too long; otherwise, try compiling a C source file with a single line `#include sys/socket.h`. Also, what does `type -a gcc` print?

Comment: type -a gcc prints /cygdrive/c/strawberry/c/bin/gcc

Comment: Please answer the rest of my question.

Comment: hi keith i reinstalled cygwin and the gcc dependices, now getting new error as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003743/missing-linux-if-h