# Missing linux/if.h

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

hello I am getting this error when using cygwin to try to make,

this is my makefile

```
flags=-g

all: icmptx

icmptx: it.o icmptx.o tun_dev.o
    gcc $(flags) -o icmptx icmptx.o it.o tun_dev.o

it.o: it.c
    gcc $(flags) -c it.c

icmptx.o: icmptx.c
    gcc $(flags) -c icmptx.c

tun_dev.o: tun_dev.c
    gcc $(flags) -c tun_dev.c

clean:
    rm -f tun_dev.o it.o icmptx.o icmptx
```

the error is

```
$ make
gcc -g -c tun_dev.c
tun_dev.c:35:22: fatal error: linux/if.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:15: recipe for target `tun_dev.o' failed
make: *** [tun_dev.o] Error 1
```

here is my tun_dev.c file

```
/*  

 */

/*
 * tun_dev.c,v 1.1.2.4 2001/09/13 05:02:22 maxk Exp
 */ 

/* #include "config.h" */

#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/if.h>

#include "vtun.h"
#include "lib.h"

/* 
 * Allocate TUN device, returns opened fd. 
 * Stores dev name in the first arg(must be large enough).
 */  
int tun_open_old(char *dev)
{
    char tunname[14];
    int i, fd;

    if( *dev ) {
       sprintf(tunname, "/dev/%s", dev);
       return open(tunname, O_RDWR);
    }

    for(i=0; i < 255; i++){
       sprintf(tunname, "/dev/tun%d", i);
       /* Open device */
       if( (fd=open(tunname, O_RDWR)) > 0 ){
          sprintf(dev, "tun%d", i);
          return fd;
       }
    }
    return -1;
}

#include <linux/if_tun.h>

/* pre 2.4.6 compatibility */
#define OTUNSETNOCSUM  (('T'<< 8) | 200) 
#define OTUNSETDEBUG   (('T'<< 8) | 201) 
#define OTUNSETIFF     (('T'<< 8) | 202) 
#define OTUNSETPERSIST (('T'<< 8) | 203) 
#define OTUNSETOWNER   (('T'<< 8) | 204)

int tun_open(char *dev)
{
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int fd;

    if ((fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR)) < 0)
       return tun_open_old(dev);

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN | IFF_NO_PI;
    if (*dev)
       strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev, IFNAMSIZ);

    if (ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *) &ifr) < 0) {
       if (errno == EBADFD) {
      /* Try old ioctl */
      if (ioctl(fd, OTUNSETIFF, (void *) &ifr) < 0) 
         goto failed;
       } else
          goto failed;
    } 

    strcpy(dev, ifr.ifr_name);
    return fd;

failed:
    close(fd);
    return -1;
}

int tun_close(int fd, char *dev)
{
    return close(fd);
}

/* Read/write frames from TUN device */
int tun_write(int fd, char *buf, int len)
{
    return write(fd, buf, len);
}

int tun_read(int fd, char *buf, int len)
{
    return read(fd, buf, len);
}
```

any idea, google shows nothing

Comment: Cygwin != Linux, so it's not surprising that `linux/if.h` is missing...

Comment: Why would you use Cygwin on Ubuntu? And how would you do that anyway?

Comment: sorry not using cygwin on ubuntu its windows 7 sorry wrong tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#include <net/if.h>
```

instead.

Comment: gives me this error tun_dev.c:65:24: fatal error: net/if_tun.h: No such file or directory   compilation terminated.                                                 Makefile:15: recipe for target `tun_dev.o' failed                       make: *** [tun_dev.o] Error 1

Comment: Obviously you need to install the dependencies of whatever it is you're trying to build. It seems you don't have them. What *is* it that you're trying to build?

Comment: this -> http://thomer.com/icmptx/ i built the server correctly and am now trying to make this on my laptop, there is no detailed readme for which dependencies that i need

Comment: @MarkLinus The answer does solve the OP's question. `linux/if.h` is Linux-specific. The correct include is `net/if.h`. And that solved the particular error message in the question. But it later turned out that the question is not really about the whole problem.

Comment: You just need to build [NET SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/download.html) in Cygwin( or not, take bins from there ), 'cause this error clearly suggests that you are lacking aformentioned unix-specific header.